# How to get an exact result of my sql query in a link table

Tags: mysql, sql

Im trying to get the groups where the brand_id's match exactly to the group.

I've tried this solution (see fiddle) but when i try to obtain one item that has a brand id that is assigned to all the groups it shows all three groups. But it should match zero, because its not an exact match.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a5b16e/2/0

I was wondering if there is a solution to this

```
SELECT  group_id as groep
FROM    mailgroups a
WHERE   a.brand_id IN (2)
GROUP BY a.group_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

this should return group 3

```
SELECT  group_id as groep
FROM    mailgroups a
WHERE   a.brand_id IN (2, 1)
GROUP BY a.group_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

and this should only return group_id 1

Comment: Please add the results you expect ? Cheers!

Comment: Please update your question and post your query in the question itself.  Thanks

Comment: @VBoka updated my questions

Comment: @devlincarnate i posted the query

Comment: @RonaldMcDonald But brand_id '2' is in all 3 groups ? It has to be only once in the group ?

Comment: yes but its not the actual group, only group_id 3 has only brand_id 2. So it should only return group 3. I made a mistake in the question my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need subqueries or joins.
Set the correct conditions in the `having` clause and remove the `where` clause:

```
SELECT  group_id as groep
FROM    mailgroups 
GROUP BY group_id
HAVING SUM(brand_id IN (2)) = 1 AND SUM(brand_id NOT IN (2)) = 0;

SELECT  group_id as groep
FROM    mailgroups 
GROUP BY group_id
HAVING SUM(brand_id IN (1, 2)) = 2 AND SUM(brand_id NOT IN (1, 2)) = 0;
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kwWkNmFTFkv9AaQSSoBcxv/0).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with sub-query:

```
select group_id
from mailgroups 
where group_id in (select group_id from mailgroups where brand_id = 2)
GROUP BY group_id
HAVING COUNT(brand_id) = 1;
```

---

```
select group_id
from mailgroups 
where group_id in (select group_id from mailgroups where brand_id in (1,2))
GROUP BY group_id
HAVING COUNT(brand_id) = 2;
```

OR with `join`:

```
select a.group_id
from mailgroups a 
left join mailgroups b
on a.id = b.id
and b.brand_id in (1,2)
GROUP BY a.group_id
HAVING COUNT(a.brand_id) = 2;
```

---

```
select a.group_id
from mailgroups a 
left join mailgroups b
on a.id = b.id
and b.brand_id in (2)
GROUP BY a.group_id
HAVING COUNT(a.brand_id) = 1;
```

Comment: This is it! you're great.

Comment: Hi @RonaldMcDonald you are welcome, I am happy to help. It is the question that matters the most.... when all is clear it is easy for me/us to help you. Cheers!